# Toggling a drop down list after click, rather than when click begins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I want my drop down list to drop down when you finish your click, rather than just as you start clicking.  How do I do that?  Thanks!

(Also, I'd appreciate it if you tell me the terminology for "beginning" and "finishing" a click!)

Comment: SO is not a place where one get code written, we help with written code. Make an effort of your own and come back with that and we'll have a look. If something is unclear, reread [ask].

Comment: Go look up `mousedown` and `mouseup`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery as follows:

```
$("div").mouseup(function() {

    // You current code to display drop down

});
```

Mousedown is the equivalent for when the user starts a click. Mouseup is when they release the click.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `.mouseup()` event instead of `.click()`

```js
$('#mybutt').mouseup(function(){
  $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mybutt">Click Here (but hold button down for a second or two)</div>
```